# How can i make a copy array function using recursion in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I've been stuck on it for a whole day. I've trying to use

```
void recCopy(int from[], int to[], int i) {

}
```

to copy from

```
void iterCopy(int from[], int to[], int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)

        to[i] = from[i];
}
```

Comment: Why are you stuck? What went wrong?

Comment: Basically, if `i>=0`, copy element at `i`, then call recursively with `i-1`.

Comment: Are you aware that [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) already exists and is what you *should* be using, instead of trying to re-implement it (badly) yourself..?

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried. You show the iterative algorithm but did not show your attempt at the recursive algorithm.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Since he's explicitly asking for an recursive copy function, I think it's save to say that his primary intention is to lern about recursion with something as simple as a copy function, and not to solve the problem of copying an array. Especially since he already has a working iterative solution.

Comment: @Bizzarrus Maybe. But the question doesn't say. And there are *so many* questions on SO that are unclear that I've just given up trying to *guess* what askers want.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the number of elements to copy, so

- if `i` is zero, you're done
- otherwise, copy one element, then copy `i-1` elements with the "tails" of the arrays.

In code:

```
void recCopy(int from[], int to[], int i) 
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        *to = *from;
        recCopy(from + 1, to + 1, i - 1);
    }
}
```